# font in wordpress not shown in this host

Tags: wordpress, fonts, themes, host

my fontface in my wordpress theme is shown in my host(cpanel) bot not shown in another host(direct admin)?
please help me!`@font-face {
    font-family: 'BYekan';
    src: url('fonts/BYekan.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BYekan.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BYekan.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/BYekan.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/BYekan.svg#CartoGothicStdBook') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}`

Comment: just copy font files to right directory on a new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 's try to use this service to see the different from your code http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator